# Why is the ItemClick event handler returning the previous clicked item?

Tags: c#, listview, event-handling, datatemplate, win-universal-app

I have a ListView with a ListView ItemTemplate with a grid.
I need the information for the row that is clicked and have `IsItemClickEnabled=True` on the ListView and a `ItemClick` event handler with a debug that shows the id of the row.

What i cant figure out is why the returned item is always the one that i clicked before, and the first click produces nothing.

Here is the markup for the ListView

```
<ListView x:Name="ListCustomerView"  ItemsSource="{x:Bind CustomersFromDB}" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListCustomerView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid IsTapEnabled="False">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{StaticResource minColumnWidth}" MaxWidth="{StaticResource maxColumnWidth}"></ColumnDefinition>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding CompanyName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FirstName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding LastName}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding Phone}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding Email}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding Adress}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="{Binding PostCode}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="7" Text="{Binding PostArea}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="8" Text="{Binding Comment}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here is the code for the CustomersFromDB ItemsSource

```
public List<Customer> CustomersFromDB { get; set; }
var db = new Database();
CustomersFromDB = db.FetchCustomer();

public List<Customer> FetchCustomer()
{
    using (SQLiteConnection _connection = new SQLiteConnection(sqlitePlatform, dbFilePath))
    {
        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
        var _customers = _connection.Table<Customer>();
        if (_customers.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (Customer customer in _customers)
            {
                customers.Add(customer);
            }
        }
        return customers;
    }
}
```

And illustration
[image: Illustration of list of customers from sqlite database displayed in the ListView using a DataTemplate with a Grid with textblocks.]

and the event handler

```
private void ListCustomerView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // BUG! the selected item is not firing correctly ending up outputting the previous clicked item
    Debug.WriteLine((sender as ListView).SelectedItem);
}
```

The customers are retrieved as seen in the illustration above but when i click a row the id is the previous that is clicked and null if it is the first click.

Why is this wierd behaviour happening?

Comment: Are you sure the order of events doesn't set the SelectedItem after the ItemClick? If you want to have an event when SelectedItem changes, there is an event for [`SelectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're using the `sender.SelectedItem` which gives you the current selection. The new selection, which is what you want, is only made after the `click` event. To get the item that you've just clicked, use the `e` parameter:

```
private void ListCustomerView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(e.ClickedItem.ToString());
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `SelectionChanged` event instead of the `ItemClick` event. This will give you new selection using the same code like yours:

```
private void ListCustomerView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine((sender as ListView).SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Of course! How stupid of me, i knew this from before but its been a while. Thank you for a well explained answer and for the tip about the SelectionChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but I'm guessing that the click event happens before the selection event happens. Thus, when your click event handler fires, the selecteditem is whatever is "previously" selected. I believe you're looking for the [ClickedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemclickeventargs.clickeditem) property on the ItemClickedEventArgs